# Why does calling mktemp from my Ruby script say permission denied?

Tags: ruby, bash, permissions

I have the following Ruby code:

```
cmd="
source= $(mktemp)
echo source
"
system("#{cmd}")
system("source= $(mktemp)")
```

I wanted the code to execute the "mktemp" command and output the temporary file name to the variable "source". However, the error message I get is:

```
sh: /tmp/tmp.EpXeLNkqjN: Permission denied

sh: /tmp/tmp.wVCqdqHSpp: Permission denied


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

The error was the same even when I ran the program as root.

However, when I run the mktemp command only, there is no problem. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `echo $source`?

Comment: @user1938444 It doesn't matter. The point is "source= $(mktemp)" won't run.

Comment: Others have answered the question, but you may also wish to consider using the mktemp ruby gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not have a space with the `=` symbol. Replace your code with

```
cmd="
source=$(mktemp)
echo $source
"
system("#{cmd}")
system("source=$(mktemp)")
```

Notice: *no space after the `=` sign*.

The problem with leaving a space after the `=` sign is that `sh` will try to execute the command given by the expansion of `$(mktemp)` (i.e., the command `/tmp/tmp.EpXeLNkqjN` or something similar — which doesn't exist) with the variable `source` being set to the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem: Invalid Shell Syntax

You have a number of errors in your code, including illegal whitespace, failure to dereference a variable properly, and potential IFS or quoting issues.

#### Solution: Use Correct Shell Syntax

Using legal Bash syntax works fine. For example:

```
cmd='source=$(mktemp); echo "$source"'
system(cmd)
```

On my system, this correctly prints the expected result on standard output, and returns correctly. For example, pry shows:

```
/tmp/tmp.of89uLTUqf
=> true
```

#### Better Solution: Use Backticks

Rather than shelling out using [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system), why not just assign the variable in Ruby using backticks? For example:

```
source = `mktemp`
# => "/tmp/tmp.KVhGMzZRiG\n"
```

This seems simpler and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're setting the file's permissions to be executable.

Comment: I don't understand see how that works but I tried it anyway and it does not work..